# Using variables without self in a class- Python

Tags: python

I have a question about why the code below executes what it does.

```
class Account:
    def __init__(self, id):
        self.id = id
        id = 800
        id = self.id + id

acc = Account(123)
print(acc.id)
```

Why would this code print 123 instead of 923? Why does the id not work inside of the class?

Comment: because you are setting `id = self.id + id` not `self.id = self.id + id`. `id != self.id`, they are two completely different variables. `acc.id` would return the value of `self.id`

Comment: Research about the `__init__` function

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You declare the variable in the scope to `self.id + id`, when the init function is finished the scope is gone and therefore `id` doesn't exist anymore.

Probably, you wanted to do:

```
self.id += id
```

Answer (score 3):

`id` is local variable inside `__init__`, you cannot access it outside this method.

When you access to `acc.id`, you access to the `id` attribute of the `Account` class.

Attributes are preceded by `self` inside the class